# Can anybody understand this specification of a feature for a horses preference to a condition?

Tags: regression, residuals, linear, feature-engineering

I have become interested statistical analysis of sports and came across a horse racing paper: "Computer Based Horse Race Handicapping and Wagering Systems: A Report" (found at: https://www.gwern.net/docs/statistics/decision/1994-benter.pdf)

One of the features the author uses in the model is a horse's preference to the distance being ran in the race. The author experiments with many different ways to calculate this feature but settled on the following specification:

[image]

The specification of this feature seems strange to me, and I can seem to gather any intuition as to why the value of this feature would show a preference to a race distance.

My understanding of the feature is as follows:

1. For each of the horses past races, use a model *(that uses no features relating to race distance)* to predict the finishing position, $p$
2. calculate the residual $r = a - p$, where $a$ is the horses actual finishing position
3. For each of the races calculate the similarity $s$ in distance to the current race's distance *(this could be through subtraction or using a Euclidian distance)*
4. For each of these races consider the points $(s, p)$, fit a line to these points
5. The value of the feature is the slope of the fitted line *(my interpretation of "the final magnitude of the estimate")* is divided by the standard error of the regression *(I interpret this to be the MSE between the points and the final line)*

I don't understand how the strength of the relationship between the residual and the similarity to the current race's distance could indicate a horse's preference to the current races distance.

Maybe my understanding of the specification of the feature is wrong or there is something else i am missing?

Comment: See, *inter alia*, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46508/919, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17336, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28474, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/.

Comment: @whuber I am unsure how these other questions relate to my question of how residuals can be used to show an entities preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is with point 4. The regression is not between $s$ and $p$, but $a$ and $r$, possibly weighted by $s$. In other words, imagine you have short and long races and a horse that likes short races. If today's race is long, it will have a negative residual and a positive residual if today's race is short. The term "residual" of course refers to regression 1. ($p$ predicting $a$), but when comes to 4. $r$ is used as a predictor.

Comment: So in step 4, we are using the residuals $r$ to predict the predicted value $p$ from the regression in step 1. When you say 'possibly weighted by $s$' do you mean that $s$ may have an influence or, indeed, may be the coefficient of the refression in step 4?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $a$ not $p$, so you predict actual performance again. I believe $s$ is used to weigh past races according to how similar they are to today's: ie use data from short races to predict short races.

Comment: Just seen your most recent edit, so when we use the residual to predict the actual finishing position, if the distance of the race had no effect _i.e. the horse had no preference_ the plot should be random and give a small regression coefficient, but if distance did have an effect then there would be some correlation and the regression coefficient would be large?

Comment: Exactly, effectively you have a variable telling you how much better/worse the horse is expected to perform for the given distance. If horses are performing randomly with respect to the distance, this should get a coefficient insignificantly different to 0.

Comment: The only thing im still not understanding is the significance of $s$ in this, could you elaborate on what you mean by weighing the past races? I dont understand what you mean by using data from short races to predict short races, surley when performing the regression instep 4, you would still use all the data?

Comment: Oh, do you mean that $s$ could be used to weight each datapoint in the least squares function, so that datapoints that come from a track with a closer distance are more important when fitting the regression in step 4 _(so, could weight terms by $\frac{1}{s}$)_, or just dont include data points in step 4 if their corrseponding $s$ value is above some threshold.

Comment: Yes the former is what I meant.