# Proving equal OLS estimators

Tags: regression, least-squares, estimators

I am trying to prove that [image] equals [image] in the following two equations given that the vector [image] are the same in both:

[image]

[image]

The only two assumptions for both equations given are the homoskedastic assumption ([image]) and the orthogonality of the vectors [image] and [image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: If you can layout what you've done, we can provide directions. Also, what does orthogonality mean here? Is it $E[x_1x_2]=0$ considering $x_1$ and $x_2$ are RVs?

Comment: Sorry, \[x_1\] and \[x_2\] are n*1 vectors. By orthogonality I mean that \[x_1 \cdot x_2^T = 0\]

Comment: This result becomes intuitively obvious and easy to prove once you understand how multiple regression can be carried out as a sequence of univariate regressions.  See, among others, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21022, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/113207/919, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46185.

Comment: @whuber thanks for those links. I think I understand it conceptually but was struggling to put it into a mathematical proof.

Comment: The key search term, then, is "Gram-Schmidt."  Or, you could use elementary Euclidean geometry, as illustrated in some of those threads I linked :-). You can also directly analyze the Normal Equations $(X^\prime X)^{-} X^\prime y = \hat\beta$ for the two models; the assumption of orthogonality enables you to simplify $X^\prime X$ in the second (two-variable) model.

Comment: I tried to do the simplification of X'X but I don't think it was getting me anywhere. What do I do after I simplify this (due to some of the values equalling zero now due to orthogonality)?