# How can we incorporate an offset into a software library which performs least squares without offset

Tags: regression, self-study, mathematical-statistics, linear-model, offset

Disclaimer: this is not homework, just preparation for an exam I'll be taking

How do I incorporate an offset term into a software library that performs least squares (without offset)?

Let me give a simple example which I'd like for the answerer to base their answer on:

> Consider a dataset $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_m,y_m)\in R \times R$, i.e., both $x_i$ and $y_i$ are real-valued scalars for all $i$. Suppose we wish to fit a linear+offset model, $$\hat{y} = ax + b$$ Suppose we have a software library that performs least squares (without offset). Explain how we can use that software library to fit the linear+offset model.

Now, by my understanding, we have that the software library performs linear regression on $X\in R^m$ and $y\in R^m$. In order to incorporate an offset, we should add a column of "ones" such that $X$ is substituted by $(X,\mathbf{1})$ where $\mathbf{1}\in R^m$ is a vector with each entry equal to $1$. We also should substitute $a\in R$ by $(a,b)$ where $b\in R$. Now, without the offset, the normal equations for computing $a$ was $$a= (X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$$ and with the above substitutions the software library calculates $$(X^TX)a + X^T\mathbf{1}b = X^Ty\\ \mathbf{1}^TXa + mb = \mathbf{1}^Ty$$

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: @StephanKolassa this is not homework, just preparation for an exam I'll be taking

Comment: It's still self-study...

Comment: You can find answers at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17336, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46185, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46151, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just subtract the offset $b$ from $y$ and proceed as normal using OLS. So your regression coefficients would simply be
$$
(X'X)^{-1}X'(y-b)
$$
Nothing related to the offset needs to be added to the design matrix ($X$). For nonlinear models, the story is different, but for OLS, it's simple.

You can see this by considering the least squares criterion that is minimized:
$$
\sum_i{(y_i-(aX_i + b_i))^2} = \sum_i{((y_i-b_i) - aX_i))^2}
$$
So performing OLS with an offset is just the same as performing OLS after subtracting the offset from the outcome.