# Generalized Linear Models - Order of Parameters Matter?

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I've got two models, the first model is my original model:

```
# Order Original
model_order_comparison = Energy ~ log(NonFat) + log(totmass)
glm_order <- glm(model_order_comparison, family=Gamma(link="log"), data=energy)
anova(glm_order , test="F")
```

The second model has the parameters in reverse order.  Why does this matter?

```
# Order Reversed
model_order_comparison = Energy ~ log(totmass) + log(NonFat)
glm_order <- glm(model_order_comparison, family=Gamma(link="log"), data=energy)
anova(glm_order , test="F")
```

What's interesting is the results are different.  My question is why?

I thought the order of parameters doesn't matter?!??!?

[image: Anova Test]

I found this, but I'm not sure it's relevant.  I'm not using any multiplication or interactions in my formula.

[Does the order of explanatory variables matter when calculating their regression coefficients?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/does-the-order-of-explanatory-variables-matter-when-calculating-their-regression)

Comment: For the *coefficients* it doesn't matter, but your tables are not looking at the coefficients. Sequential deviance of course differs generally on order, just as sequential SS does in ordinary regression.

Answer (score 5):

The order of the parameters doesn't affect the model being estimated or the regression coefficients or the standard errors or anything.  Your issue is different; it's about *which models* you are comparing.

If you have a full model with `Y~A+B`, there are *three* simpler models

1. `Y~A`
2. `Y~B`
3. `Y~1`

`anova` has to pick *two* comparisons to do.  It compares your full model to one of 1 and 2, and then compares that model to 3. How does it decide which of 1 and 2 to use? It looks at the order in the full model, sees that `A` is first, and so compares to model 1.

You could do this other ways.  For example, you might say you wanted to compare your full model to 1 and to 2, and not to 3.  There are other functions that let you do this (eg `car::Anova`).

Better practice, though, is for *you* to decide what models *you* want to compare.  You can fit your full model and `model1` (fitting model 1) and `model2` fitting model 2. After you do that

```
anova(glm_order, model1)
```

will return the same thing, regardless of the order you used in fitting your full model

```
anova(glm_order, model2)
```

will always return the same thing, regardless of the order you used in fitting your full model.

The 'automatic' choice of which models to compare is a hangover from decades ago, when computing was scarce and expensive and happened overnight in computer centres.  Now that computing is simple and inexpensive and interactive, you can just ask for the comparisons you want and not ask for the ones you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

In regression it doesn't depend on the order of independent variables (covariates), in anova it does, since it is a sequential analysis (it looks at the variance/deviance explained by given covariate with the variance/deviance of the previous covariates already filtered out). You are looking at the anova results.